# Application running even when closed?

Tags: android

I want my app to update itself even if it is closed. Like the way that restaurant city (game) for example, tells you when something is ready even if the app is closed. I want it to collect information, for example, in the game one object can be used only after 4 hours, so when the player closed the game, the game will still check for the time and send notification when the object is ready.

BTW: I am using andEngine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for those tasks.

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user...

Comment: I looked there but didn't really understand it, is there a good tutorial about it?

Comment: Checkout [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) Tutorial with example of MediaPlayer which keeps playing though the Application gets closed.

Comment: Thanks i will check it later when i get home.